# SQL Server Database Update using Multithreading

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a requirement to update 20 tables in a SQL Server database in a C# application. For better performance, I am planning to use multiple threads for updating tables. Could anybody refer any example link which gives idea for this kind of operation?

Also, as per my understanding, if I use multi threading, then I have to use different connection object for each thread. In that case, how I can put multiple threads in a single transaction, which are basically using different connection objects?

Comment: Did you try using **one** stored procedure call which may then update 20 tables. so you would not have to open (even multithreaded) 20 connections?

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple threads? You will get better performance  only if _constructing_ sql statements takes significant time. If most of the time is spent _executing_ statements then using multiple threads might even make whole process slower.

Comment: Why would you need to multithread this? It just feels like a bad idea. 20 tables is nothing.

Comment: Write some code to just do the 20 updates first! Don't just jump on multi-threading to "speed" it up before you even know how long it's taking and where the time is going (code vs DB).....

Comment: I will be using 20 different Stored procedures.Those procedures will be called from relevant Data access methods.

Comment: So if Update "333" (some random update) to Table15 doesn't work, does that not matter to the entire operation?

Comment: Aren't you worried about doing this in a transaction (all or nothing)? Even if you send 20 INSERTs at once to the server, think about this: Assuming you have Enterprise Edition, how many processors do you have? 20? Ok, how many hard-drives? 20? Is each table partitioned in some crazy way that they each have thier own hard drive?  Maybe you need to rethink what you are doing, not just jump to 20 threads in your client app.

Answer (score 1):

Use TPL (task parallel library), here is an example http://safeery2k.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/ado-net-using-tpl/

Answer (score 0):

20 tables to update at once is pretty crazy.

If 20 stored procedures is the ONLY way to do what needs to get done then create one more stored procedure that will call the 20 stored procedures for you and simply use this stored procedure.

This way if an error/exception occurs you will be able to rollback the mods AND it is now contained in one location - nice and easy (all things considered).

I'm very glad I don't have to deal with the situation you're in with this one! Good luck with this!